# Max size of varchar(max) in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, varchar

I would like to know what is the maximum size of `varchar` in SQL Server 2000. While I was googling somewhere it was written 8000 characters and somewhere it was written 8060 bytes. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 24):

Varchar is 8000 and nvarchar is 4000.

Here's the varchar msdn reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: @Kumar: yes, for VARCHAR, 1 character = 1 byte; for NVARCHAR, 1 character = 2 byte

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that.  Short version is that varchar and nvarchar don't use the space until you actually put data there.

Comment: This just got upvoted today. If you're still reading this and worried about Sql Server 2000, you should know that we're less than 3 months away from the official End of Life for this version of Sql Server (April 9, 2013). After this point, even critical security issues will no longer be fixed. You should seriously consider moving to a current version of Sql Server ASAP.

Answer (score 11):

A SQL Server data page has 8k: 8192 bytes. From this a portion is reserved for the page header, leaving 8060 bytes the maximum lnegth a single row can have. In a row, the varbinary(n), varchar(n) and nvarchar(n) types cannot exceed 8000 bytes, which means that varchar(8000) is the maximum Ascii length and nvarchar(4000) is the maximum Unicode length (since Unicode stores each character on 2 bytes).

The best explanation of all these details comes from [Inside the Storage Engine: Anatomy of a page](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-page.aspx).

Comment: +1 Small tidbit: Unicode doesn't store each character in 2 bytes. That depends on the encoding. UTF-8 and UTF-16 are variable length encodings, UTF-32 is the only one that's fixed size that I know of. Other encodings exist (UCS-2, UTF-7). Internally, Microsoft typically uses UTF-16, where the default size of a character is 2 bytes. This is true for at least all .NET-based products and for SQL Server.

Comment: @abel: SQL Server [uses UCS-2LE encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189617(v=sql.105).aspx), which is exactly 2 bytes per character. I agree though that 'Unicode', as worded in the post, does not have strictly 2 bytes per character.

Comment: Yes, you're right on UCS-2, I keep forgetting that, it's one of my major gripes, as it only allows BMP characters. Tx for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember it is 8000 Chars.

For Nvarchar it is 4000.

Comment: @Kumar: **yes!** For `varchar` it's 1 char = 1 byte, for `nvarchar` it's 1 char = 2 byte

Answer (score 2):

The maximum size of varchar(max) is large (2GB or 2Gchars, I think). The maximum value you can specify for n in varchar(n) is 8000, and for nvarchar it's 4000.

Comment: You're right, but then the question is void. The second part of my answer still holds