# Varchar(max) in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, variables, sql-server-2000

In a stored procedure I must have a `varchar` variable of max size.

```
declare @a varchar(max)
```

This works on SQL Server 2005\08\12 but it doesn't work on 2000.

I don't need that the stored procedure works on SQL Server 2000, I only need that this instruction compile without error.

I have think that a possible solution is something like:

```
declare @SqlText nvarchar(100) set @SqlText = 'declare @a varchar(max)'
exec sp_executesql @SqlText
```

But in this way if I try to use the variable `@A` compiling I get an error that says that I must declare the variable @a.

Is there any possible solution?

Comment: Do you build database project using SSDT?

Comment: The answer is already provided in this answer
[varchar(max) MS SQL Server 2000, problems?][1], and here, [Max size of varchar(max) in SQL Server 2000][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/737791/3021830
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2077753/3021830

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2000 doesn't support `VARCHAR(MAX)` but you can instead use `TEXT` which is still supported in SQL Server 2012 (and 2014). It will be [removed in the future](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187993.aspx), but it will work for you now.

```
DECLARE @a TEXT
```